# AMPL, set 1..T is not working

Tags: set, command, display, ampl

The `1..T` function is not working for me, and I don't know why. My code looks like this:

```
set TIME;

data;

set TIME = 1..8760 by 3;

display TIME;
```

Here I want it to display `1, 4, 7, 10`, and so on, but it just goes `1..8760 by 3`. How can I fix this so that I don't have to write 8,760 different numbers?

Thankful for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any error in your code. I tried in my AMPL IDE:

[AMPL IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs7Tl.png)

I suppose that when you write "data" is that your code is in the .dat file and when you write "display" is your .run file

What are you using to write your model?? NEOS SERVER or the IDE??

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the first two lines of your code.

It looks as if the format you're using to specify TIME only works in "model" mode; in "data" mode, the same text is interpreted as declaring a set of literals "3", "by", and "1..8760". (Quick test: if you type `display card(TIME);` you get a value of 3, telling you that there are exactly 3 members in this set.)

[Section 5.2 of the AMPL Book](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/08-sets1.pdf) recommends using a "x..y by z" type declaration in the model (with x, y, z as declared params) and then specifying values for x, y, z in the data.

Note that starting at 1 and increasing in steps of 3 won't actually get to 8760 exactly, so you might want to change your start to 0 or 3, or your end to 8761, if you want equal gaps between the numbers.